# How to make SidebarModule push content on Menu Button click using ng-sidebar?

Tags: angular

I am using SidebarModule for sliding Menu in Shared Component but animation and sliding fails.

Here is my Code:

HTML:

```
 <ng-sidebar-container>
      <ng-sidebar
      [(opened)]="_opened"
      [mode]="_MODES[_modeNum]"
      [animate]="_animate"
      [position]="_POSITIONS[_positionNum]"
      [closeOnClickOutside]="_closeOnClickOutside">
    // Menu Code
</ng-sidebar>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

Component :

```
  public _opened: boolean = false;
  public _modeNum: number = 2;
  public _positionNum: number = 1;
  public _animate: boolean = true;
  public _closeOnClickOutside: boolean = true;
  public _MODES: Array<string> = ['over', 'push', 'slide'];
  public _POSITIONS: Array<string> = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below steps might help you if you are trying to call this module in other components as well via shared component.

Shared Component HTML:

```
 <ng-sidebar-container>
      <ng-sidebar
      [(opened)]="_opened"
      [mode]="_MODES[_modeNum]"
      [animate]="_animate"
      [position]="_POSITIONS[_positionNum]"
      [closeOnClickOutside]="_closeOnClickOutside">
    // Menu Div Here
</ng-sidebar>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

Shared Component TS:

```
   public _opened: boolean = false;
   public _modeNum: number = 1;
   public _positionNum: number = 1;
   public _animate: boolean = true;
   public _closeOnClickOutside: boolean = true;
   public _MODES: Array<string> = ['over', 'push', 'slide'];
   public _POSITIONS: Array<string> = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'];
   public _menu: boolean;
   public isMenuActive : string;

  constructor(private menuService: MenuService {
  }

  public _MenuOpened(): void {
    this._opened = !this._opened;
    this._menu = this._opened;
    this.menuService._menu.next(this._opened);
  }
```

In the above code, **_modeNum** Position should be 1 as it pushes the content. And **_MenuOpened()** method is called on Menu button click and the boolean variable is subscribed.

Shared Component Service:

```
export class MenuService {

constructor() { }

public _MenuOpened: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

}
```

Now, Calling the above shared Component in other components:

Sample Component TS:

```
public isMenuOpened: boolean;
constructor( private menuService: MenuService) {
    this.menuService.isMenuOpened.subscribe(value => {
      this.isMenuOpened = value;
    });
  }
```

And in the Sample Component HTML, handle the div styles conditionally with **isMenuOpened** Variable.

Answer (score 2):

yes, **_modeNum** value should be 1. Try changing the code as below:

```
   public _opened: boolean = false;
   public _modeNum: number = 1;
   public _positionNum: number = 1;
   public _animate: boolean = true;
   public _closeOnClickOutside: boolean = true;
   public _MODES: Array<string> = ['over', 'push', 'slide'];
   public _POSITIONS: Array<string> = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'];
```